# Qualtrics Matrix Likert Drag & Drop: Get bucket ID

Tags: qualtrics

I'm trying to implement the solution linked below to the problem of restricted a Qualtrics matrix bucket from adding a new element after it is filled to a certain number.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50936402/22228594

Does anyone know how I get the IDs for the buckets, i.e. to replace 'QID1group0' with? I can't seem to find that anywhere. I know the ID for this matrix question is QID1, but I don't know what the full bucket IDs are.
The recode values for my four buckets titled "None", "Low", "Medium", "High" are respectively 1, 2, 3, 4. But trying 'QID1group1' doesn't make anything happen.

Here is the code I'm using, as per that answer linked above.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() { /Place your JavaScript here to run when the page loads/jQuery(function() { jQuery("ul.droptrue").sortable({ connectWith: "ul", });

jQuery("ul.dropfalse").sortable({ connectWith: "ul", dropOnEmpty: false });

jQuery("#QID1group1,#QID1group2, #QID1group3, #QID1group4").disableSelection();

jQuery("#QID1group1,#QID1group2, #QID1group3, #QID1group4").on("sortreceive", function(event, ui) { var jQuerylist = jQuery(this);

if (jQuerylist.children().length > 1) {
    jQuery(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
}

}); 
});

});`
```

When I use the above code even while trying a few different things for those IDs, nothing happens. I'm still able to add >1 elements to each bucket.

Chat GPT also provided the following when I asked it about this, but it doesn't work either. Though I would include anyway

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() { /Place your JavaScript here to run when the page loads/

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() { jQuery(function() { jQuery("ul.droptrue").sortable({ connectWith: "ul", receive: function(event, ui) { if (jQuery(this).children().length > 1) { jQuery(ui.sender).sortable('cancel'); } } });

  jQuery("ul.dropfalse").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    dropOnEmpty: false
  });

  jQuery("#QID1group1, #QID1group2, #QID1group3, #QID1group4").disableSelection();
});

}); });
```